# How did Mineta Minoru get into UA?

Tags: my-hero-academia

U.A. is the #1 ranked High School for heroics and is considered as the top Hero Academy in the world. As such it as a pretty low acceptance rate. With plenty of other students who may have aspired to be in UA, it is surprising that Mineta Minoru was able to get in to UA.

His quirk seems pretty useless in battle. Additionally he was just above Midoriya in Aizawa's Quick Apprehension Test at 19th rank in the class. He has been shown to be a coward and was pretty scared when the villains attacked.

How was he able to defeat enough machines to pass the UA high entrance exam?

Answer (score 10):

Though Mineta has been shown to be dumb, pervert and a coward, he has very high Intelligence, Co-operation and Technique rating from the databook. [Mineta Minoru - Quirks and Abilities](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Minoru_Mineta#Quirk_and_Abilities)

Further clearance was then provided by the author himself,

> I've received a number of letters asking how on earth he managed to pass the Entrance Exam. So I'll take this chance to explain it. First, as Izuku himself said, his quirk is quite strong. **And remember that the rules of the Entrance Exam was to immobilize or render the villain-bots unable to function anymore, not necessarily destroy them.** As such he could trap them against walls, or stick them to the ground, or even plug up their muzzles to earn points. [Mineta Minor - Author Notes](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-uHkT2brig40/VO1MWCCFdtI/AAAAAAABLJ0/BWDtpZMoXU4/s0/007.png)

Thus Mineta though typically using his quirk just for throwing the balls has the technique and intelligence to stop the villain bots and rack up the points pretty easily, hence gaining admission to UA!