# How did Hagakure pass the UA entrance exam?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Since the theme of the entrance exam was to defeat the robots, characters like Shinso,despite having awesome quirks, won't be able to pass. But Hagakure, who was having a quirk good for stealth but absolutely useless for combat (well that might be an exaggeration, but I'm pretty sure she can't fight robots with that it), passed the test. How is this possible, considering we already have a character who couldn't join hero class just because his quirk was non-combat type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Toru and Koji pass the entrance exam in My Hero Academia?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/how-did-toru-and-koji-pass-the-entrance-exam-in-my-hero-academia)

Answer (score 0):

The test gave the option of either destroying or disabling the robots. I can't find the original statement, but the general consensus is that Horikoshi at some point said that there was a button to disable the robots. This would allow Hagakure and such to disable the robots by sneaking around them and pushing the button. However, Shinso's quirk only works on human beings, he had neither the combat nor stealth abilities to disable the robots.

Comment: Also, every student got some points for rescuing "citizens" from the robots, not only for destroying/incapacitating them.